# Java:compare an input to a char Array using charAt

Tags: java, arrays, count, compare, charat

I would like to compare String input to the char[] List.If a letter inside the string is equal to the char[] List, the count should iterate but it always prints out 0. Thanks!

```
    char[] List={'a','b','c','d'};

    int count=0;
    for(int i=1;i<List.length-1;i++){
        if(input.charAt(i)==List[i]){
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: for one, in code number always start at 0, so `i = 0` not `i = 1` and you do not need to take 1 away from List.length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are skipping the first and last characters of the `List` array, and beside that, you only compare the i'th input character to the i'th character in your `List` array. You need a nested loop in order to compare all the characters of the input String to all the characters of the `List` array.

```
char[] List={'a','b','c','d'};

int count=0;
for(int i=0;i<List.length;i++){
    for (int j=0;j<input.length();j++) {
        if(input.charAt(j)==List[i]){
            count++;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Im new to java programming.

Answer (score 2):

Array index starts from 0 and goes upto n-1, So your loop should be:

```
for(int i=0;i<List.length;i++){
    if(input.charAt(i)==List[i]){//assuming you have same number of characters in input as well as List and you want to compare ith element of input with ith element of List
        count++;
    }
}
```

if you need to compare an element within the input with any of characters in list then you could do something like:

```
 if (input.indexOf(List[i], 0) >= 0) {
     count++;
 }
```

Comment: In my opinion he wants to iterate over the input, not the char array.

Comment: @Matthias I think he wants to check if characters in input has characters from label and i have updated the answer for the same.

Comment: exactly what I wanted to do +1